# How to take one element out of an array and put in front?

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,1,3]
```

What is the best way to get `b` from `a`?

My inelegant solution:

```
x = 2
y = a - [x]
b = y.unshift(x)
```

Comment: Please provide more information: The array always has 3 elements? You always want to extract the 2nd one?

Comment: length of array should be flexible.

Comment: Ok, so what if the array has 1 element? 0? 4? 42?

Comment: array has 2 or more unique elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.unshift a.delete(2)
```

This appends the recently deleted object (here `2`).

Beware that, if the object in question appears more than once in the array, all occurences will be deleted.

In case you want only the first occurrence of an object to be moved, try this:

```
a = [1,2,3,2]
a.unshift a.delete_at(a.index(2))
# => [2, 1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: If there are several `2` in the array, it will delete all of them.

Comment: This is right (but not specified in the question) :) (I should add that to my answer nevertheless)

Comment: You could use a combination of [index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index) and [delete_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at)

Comment: Right! Got the same idea and already edited my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a.unshift a.slice!(a.index(2)||0)
# => [2, 1, 3]
```

- If there are multiple instances, only the first instance is moved to the front.
- If the element doesn't exist, then `a` is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to move elements of an array arbitrarily, you could do something like this:

**Code**

```
# Return a copy of the receiver array, with the receiver's element at
# offset i moved before the element at offset j, unless j == self.size,
# in which case the element at offset i is moved to the end of the array. 

class Array
  def move(i,j)
    a = dup
    case
    when i < 0 || i >= size
      raise ArgumentError, "From index is out-of-range"
    when j < 0 || j > size
      raise ArgumentError, "To index is out-of-range"
    when j < i
      a.insert(j, a.delete_at(i))
    when j == size
      a << a.delete_at(i)
    when j > i+1
      a.insert(j-1, a.delete_at(i))
    else
      a
    end
  end
end
```

With Ruby v2.1, you could optionally replace `class Array` with `refine Array`.  ([Module#refine](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-refine) was introduced experimentally in v2.0, but was changed substantially in v2.1.)

**Demo**

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

arr.move(2,1) #=> [1, 3, 2, 4, 5] 
arr.move(2,2) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
arr.move(2,3) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
arr.move(2,4) #=> [1, 2, 4, 3, 5] 
arr.move(2,5) #=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 3] 
arr.move(2,6) #=> ArgumentError: To index is out-of-range
```